# FZF Immediately Gives me the Dreaded Bell When first Tyring to use it

Tags: plugin-fzf, fzf

Not sure why but if I open vim, and try and use `FZF`, I get a bell noise when using my mappings for it. Doing `:FZF` will work just fine, but I have a mapping `nnoremap <leader>ff :FZF<cr>` And that gives me the bell error noise! Seems after doing other actions my mapping works, have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Is your timeout too short to get the three characters `<leader>ff`? Do you have another command that might be "eating" the `<leader>` character? Try pressing `<esc>` or Ctrl+C first, then see if the mapping works... Can you try mapping it to a simpler or different key combination (perhaps just simply `<C-p>`) and see if that works?

Comment: do you have space or something at the end of the mapping?